# Display Flashing with Kaby Lake on 16.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

I've been trying to get Ubuntu 16.10 working on my custom PC with Intel core i3-7100 (Kaby Lake), but can't get the graphics working properly. My display flashes off regularly - about once every second if I use resolution 1920x1080, rendering it practically unusable, and once every 5-10 seconds with resolution 800x600. I'm fairly certain it's a driver issue because everything worked fine when I installed Windows, and also works in Ubuntu if I switch to the console (Ctrl-Alt-F1).

It seems others have been [able to run Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-i3-7100&num=1) with the same processor, so I'm not sure what's different about my setup. I've tried suggestions online to use the latest kernel version (tried both 4.9.7 and 4.10-rc6 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), updated graphics drivers from Oibaf's PPA, used Intel's Graphics Update Tool, and put magical incantations in Xorg conf files (including turning DRI off, which at least reduced the frequency of the flashing a little), but ultimately to no avail.

I don't see anything relevant in `dmesg` output. What else can I try to fix/diagnose the issue?

Comment: I suggest reporting a bug to Launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix it! Turns out when I use Ubuntu in BIOS mode (rather than UEFI) it works perfectly. I'm guessing it's some compatibility issue with my Gigabyte H270N-WIFI motherboard. Had no idea EFI problems could cause strange display issues like this.